# Can I use a single Custom Adapter for multiple activities in the same project?

Tags: android, listview, custom-adapter

I am creating a food ordering android app. In this app I have already used custom adapter for image flipper (Image Slideshow) and now I want to use it for custom Listview.
So, can anybody guide me how to do it

This is code for the custom adapter

```
package com.example.zaheerulislam.thedelicioso;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context context;
    int[] SliderImages;
    String[] SliderNames;
    LayoutInflater inflter;

public CustomAdapter(Context applicationContext, String[] SliderNames, int[] SliderImages) {
    this.context = applicationContext;
    this.SliderImages = SliderImages;
    this.SliderNames = SliderNames;
    inflter = (LayoutInflater.from(applicationContext));

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return SliderNames.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    view = inflter.inflate(R.layout.activity_flipper_items, null);
    TextView fruitName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.fruitName);
    ImageView fruitImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.fruitImage);
    fruitName.setText(SliderNames[position]);
    fruitImage.setImageResource(SliderImages[position]);
    return view;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use same adapter for image flipper and `ListView`, but not `RecyclerView`. You can extend your adapter by `ArrayAdapter` and you are good to go as it has `getView` method to populate your custom views so is needed for `ListView`.

Although `RecyclerView` adapter does not have this method so you will have to use `ListView` only in all of your project.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use same adapter for multiple Activities. If view of single item is not much different then you can manage easily using ViewType.
If item view is more different or complicated then as per android standers must be use different adapter.